# What is the difference between p = *a[0] and p=&a[0]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#define N 20
int a[2N], i, *p, sum;

p = a;


/* p=a is equivalent to p = *a[0];
• p is assigned 300.
• Pointer arithmetic provides an alternative to array indexing.
• p=a; is equivalent to p=&a[=]; (p is assigned 300)
```

Here I am not getting how `p=*a[0]` and `p=&a[0]` are same? `*a[0]` references the element at the memory address.

Comment: `p=a` and `p=&a[0]` are same, not what you wrote!!!

Comment: I think it's a typo - there are actually at least two typos in there, so I'm guessing whoever wrote this doesn't have very good attention to detail.

Comment: It's commented, but i'm curious, what is `p=&a[=]`? Any ideas  @PaulR sir? (kind of `gcc` extension?)

Comment: No, I think that's just another typo, given that `=` is close to `0` on most keyboards.

Comment: my point iz same i just want to confirm i read it somewhere online so i was a bit confused now i m clear about  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of `p = &a[0]` is as follows

**For example :**

```
 int a[4];
                        a[0]  a[1]  a[2]  a[3]
            a --------> [   ][    ][    ][    ]
```

**Equivalents**

```
 // Reference
 &a[0] = a;
 &a[1] = a+1; 
 ...
 &a[3] = a+3;

 // Value
 a[0]  = *a
 a[1]  = *(a+1)
 ..
 a[3]  = *(a+3)
```

In arrays of C programming, name of the array always points to the first element of an array. Here, address of first element of an array is `&a[0]`. Also, `a` represents the address of the pointer where it is pointing i.e., base address . Hence, `&a[0]` is equivalent to `a`, so `p = a` or `p = &a[0]` both are same.

Answer (score 5):

**Point 1**

Do your understand, here `int a[2N]` is **invalid** code?

This `2N` does not mean `2*N`, rather this `N` is considered as a *suffix* (to integer literal `2`) which is invalid.

<sup>Thanks to Mr **@ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc** for the comment below.</sup>

If you wanted something like `int a[40]`, write `int a [2*N]`

**Point 2**

> *`p=*a[0]` and `p=&a[0]` are same*

No, they're not same. Actually, with the current code snippet, `*a[0]` is *invalid*.

FWIW, `p = a;` and `p = &a[0];` are same, because the *array name* represents the *base address*, i.e., the address of the first element in the array.

Comment: I think `2N` is a single token, so it'll return some error like invalid suffix. Only `2##N` gets expanded to 220

Comment: Yeah I know that, I thought you mistakenly wrote that, sorry, sorry for the problem, totally misunderstanding @SouravGhosh

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, you're very right. I overlooked that angle. Will update, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`p = a` and `p = &a[0]` are indeed equivalent. In this case, you assign the address of the first element in the array to `p` (because the name of the array = pointer to its first element). `p=*a[0]` and `p=&a[0]` are not the same; `*a[0]` requires that `a` be an array of *pointers*, and dereferences its first member.